# $\operatorname{Var}(X^2)$, if $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\sigma^2$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

What would be $\operatorname{Var}(X^2)$, if $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\sigma^2$?

Comment: $Var[X] \stackrel{d}{=} \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2 \to Var[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^4] - (\mathbb{E}[X^2])^2 $ or perhaps even more confusingly $Var[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^4] - (Var[X^2] + (\mathbb{E}[X])^2)$

Comment: In general there is no readily available formula. You can use delta method to get the approximation: here is [the relevant question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/variance-of-a-function-of-one-random-variable/5790#5790).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error propagation via Taylor's rule (aka "delta" method) --

$$\operatorname{Var}(X^2) \approx 4\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}(X)^2 \operatorname{Var}(X)$$

Comment: Do you mean $4 E(X)^2 Var(X)$ ?

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder what happens in the delta method when $E(x)=0$, as in the standard Normal distribution ;-).

Comment: @whuber - you can add another term to the Taylor expansion underlying the delta method; if you do this, you get $\text{Var}(X^2) \approx \mu_4(X)$, the fourth central moment of $X$.

Comment: @Elvis - you're right; I've fixed the formatting to make it clearer.

Comment: @Elvis, no, I meant X^2, but you make a good point.  This applies only to heteroskedastic errors, so.. not very useful to the actual question that was asked!

Comment: ?! $\mathrm{Var} \left(X^2\right) = 4 X^2 \mathrm{Var} (X)$ doesn’t make any sense, on the left side you have a constant and on the right a random variable.

Comment: I don't get it. You mean if $E(x) = 0$ then $Var(X^2) ≈ 0$?

Answer (score 13):

As a simple example of the responses of @user2168 and @mpiktas:
The variance of the set of values 1,2,3 is 0.67, while the variance of its square is 10.89. On the other hand, the variance of 2,3,4 is also 0.67, but the variance of the squares is 24.22.

These are just variances for finite sets of data, but the idea extends to distributions.

Comment: Another similar example: if +1 and -1 are equally likely then the variance is 1, but the variance of the squares is 0; if 0 and 2 are equally likely then the variance is again 1 but the variance of the squares is 4.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that the relationship between then is not constant by taking $X'=X+c$. Shifting a distribution by a constant doesn't affect the variance, but $Var((X+c)^2)$ can be made arbitrarily large. $Var(X^2)$ is a fourth-order statistic (i.e. is a combination of moments of order four and smaller), and cannot be written in terms of lower order statistics such as variance and mean.

Answer (score -1):

Error propagation via Taylor's rule (aka "delta" method) --

$$\operatorname{Var}(X^2) \approx  4\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}(X)^2 \operatorname{Var}(X) - \operatorname{Var}(X)^2 $$

Sorry i have expanded the taylor's rule in one extra order, because to just approximate the $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ linearly caused some problem with my algorithm, thought it would help other people to realize it's not linear...

Comment: -1 You propose a solution that is *negative* whenever $E(X)$ is sufficiently small, which should make you uncomfortable, and you also suggest, incorrectly, that there is an "exact solution."  There is no universal solution without making an explicit assumption about $E(X^4).$

Comment: sorry i ran into this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/variance-of-a-function-of-one-random-variable/5790#5790 which have \begin{align}
Var(f(X))=[f'(EX)]^2Var(X)-\frac{[f''(EX)]^2}{4}Var^2(X)+\tilde{T}_3
\end{align} . i was using the                                         \begin{align}           \text{Var}(X^2) \approx 4\mathbb{E}(X)^2\text{Var}(X) \end{align}  only and run into problems . and you are right since $ \tilde{T}_3 $ contains more than f'''(EX)* something, but ( f'''(EX)+something)*something