# Expected value calculation

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, expected-value

I have great difficulty in calculating $\mathrm{E}\left(\sqrt{T_{1}  T_{2}}\right)$ where $T_{i}$ is a random variable distributed according to the  [Birnbaum-Saunders distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Saunders_distribution). Are there any suggestions on how to calculate the expression?

The approximation is in Kundu et. al 2010 but when programming in [R](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fkz7p8fqba7tvn/aproximation.R) the approximation diverges, I'm thinking that the error is in the approach and maybe can meet other approach.

Comment: Are the parameters for the $T_i$ the same? Do you need an exact answer or is an asymptotic approximation acceptable?

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b for you interest, $(T_{1},T_{2})\sim BS_2(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2,\rho)$ (see [link](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~kundu/paper153.pdf)), not an exact value but an acceptable approximation would be great. Best regards.

Comment: In the Kundu et al 2010 paper you linked, the expression for this expectation is given in page 118. What is the nature of your difficulty with it?

Comment: Thanks @AlecosPapadopoulos for you interest. When programming the expression presented in Kundu pag. 118, the expression diverges (see [R](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qax6x9rdj6pbewz/Matriz%20informacion%20observada.R)  program that implements ) and therefore I think the expression given on pag. 119 has some error.

Comment: Interesting. If you are certain about that, you should contact the authors of the paper -mistakes in complicated mathematical calculations are sometimes inevitable, and it is good when they are found -and corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlecosPapadopoulos, I just wrote an email to Kundu consulting on the approach he uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to compute $\text{E}(T_1 T_2)$ and $\text{Var}(T_1 T_2)$, you can use Taylor series expansion to get an approximation ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables), also see [this example here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41896/varx-is-known-how-to-calculate-var1-x/41905#41905)):

$g(X)= g(\mu+X-\mu) = g(\mu)+g'(\mu) (X-\mu) + \frac{g''(\mu)}{2} (X-\mu)^2 + ...$

So

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{E}(g(X))&=&  g(\mu)+g'(\mu) \text{E}(X-\mu) + \frac{g''(\mu)}{2} \text{E}((X-\mu)^2) + ...\\
&=& g(\mu)+ 0 + \frac{g''(\mu)}{2} \text{Var}(X) + ...
\end{eqnarray}

Hence

$\text{E}(\sqrt{T_1 T_2}) \approx \sqrt{\text{E}(T_1 T_2)} -\frac{1}{8}\text{E}(T_1 T_2)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \text{Var}(T_1 T_2)$

(assuming I made no errors)

You can carry the expansion out further, but usually for expectations it is only taken out to the variance term.

Comment: Thanks very you much @Glen_b. I will review their expression.

Comment: The difficulty now is to calculate $E(T_{1}T_{2})$, the paper of [link](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~kundu/paper153.pdf) Kundu et. the 2010 uses an approach that when I program in R diverges, so I think something is wrong.

Comment: $\text{E}(T_1T_2) = \text{Cov}(T_1,T_2) + \text{E}(T_1)\text{E}(T_2)= \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 + \text{E}(T_1)\text{E}(T_2)$

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b for you help, also share a formula more see [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15978/variance-of-product-of-dependent-variables)  $Var(T_{1}T{2})=Cov(T_{1}^2,T_{2}^2) + (Var(T_{1}) + E(T_{1})^2)(Var(T_{2}) + E(T_{2})^2) - (Cov(T_{1},T_{2}) + E(T_{1})E(T_{2}))^2$

Comment: Good. If you were happy with the first formula I was planning to go dig up the corresponding formula for the variance. Looks like you're able to at least compute the approximation. If the distribution isn't fairly 'tight' around the mean (small coefficient of variation, in the sense of zero being more than a couple of sds from the mean, for example), then the approximation often isn't so great.

Comment: By approximation of Taylor [link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Taylor_series) $E(\sqrt{T_{1}T_{2}})=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\frac{(-1)^{i+j}(2j)!(2i)!2^{2i+2j-2}}{(1-2i)(1-2j)(i!j!)^{2}4^{i+j}\alpha_{1}^{2i-1} \alpha_{2}^{2j-1}}E(Z_{1}^{-(2i -1)}Z_{2}^{-(2j -1)})$ where $T_{i}=\beta_{j}\left[\frac{1}{2}\alpha_{i}Z_{i} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\alpha_{i}Z_{i}\right)^2 + 1}  \right]^{2}$, with $Z_{i} \sim N(0,1)$, $i=1,2$. The difficulty is finding the expectation $E(Z_{1}^{-(2i -1)}Z_{2}^{-(2j -1)})$

Comment: If that's right, the term in front of the $E$ surprises me. I see some simplifications there, by the way. If you carry the Taylor expansion out to infinity then (assuming it converges) it's not an approximation.

Comment: This link contains the program into [R] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fkz7p8fqba7tvn/aproximation.R)  where the approach, however get very large values.