# What is the covariance/correlation between $X$ and $X^2$ (without assuming normality)?

Tags: correlation, covariance, moments

If $X \sim \text{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ then it is well-known that $X$ and $X^2$ are uncorrelated (i.e., they have zero covariance).  There are also certain distributions for which these random variables are independent.  However, uncorrelatedness does not hold in general --- it occurs for the normal distribution with zero mean and certain other cases.

What is the general formula for $\mathbb{C}(X,X^2)$ without assuming normality or zero mean?  What is the general formula for the corresponding correlation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The general form of the covariance depends on the first three moments of the distribution.  To facilitate our analysis, we suppose that $X$ has mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$ and skewness $\gamma$.  The covariance of interest exists if $\gamma < \infty$ and does not exist otherwise.  Using the [relationship between the raw moments and the cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Cumulants_and_moments), you have the general expression:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{C}(X,X^2)
&= \mathbb{E}(X^3) - \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(X^2) \\[6pt]
&= ( \mu^3 + 3 \mu \sigma^2 + \gamma \sigma^3 ) - \mu ( \mu^2 + \sigma^2 ) \\[6pt]
&= 2 \mu \sigma^2 + \gamma \sigma^3. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The special case for an unskewed distribution with zero mean (e.g., the centred normal distribution) occurs when $\mu = 0$ and $\gamma = 0$, which gives zero covariance.  Note that the absence of covariance occurs for any unskewed centred distribution, though independence holds for certain particular distributions.

---

**Extension to correlation:** If we further assume that $X$ has finite kurtosis $\kappa$ then using [this variance result](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452540/) it can be shown that:

$$\mathbb{V}(X) = \sigma^2
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\mathbb{V}(X^2) = 4 \mu^2 \sigma^2 + 4 \mu \gamma \sigma^3 + (\kappa-1) \sigma^4.$$

It then follows that:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{Corr}(X,X^2)
&= \frac{\mathbb{Cov}(X,X^2)}{\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(X) \mathbb{V}(X^2)}} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{2 \mu \sigma^2 + \gamma \sigma^3}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 \cdot (4 \mu^2 \sigma^2 + 4 \mu \gamma \sigma^3 + (\kappa-1) \sigma^4)}} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{2 \mu + \gamma \sigma}{\sqrt{4 \mu^2 + 4 \mu \gamma \sigma + (\kappa-1) \sigma^2}}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

For the special case of a random variable with zero mean we have $\mu=0$ which then gives:

$$\mathbb{Corr}(X,X^2)
= \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\kappa-1}},$$

which is the scale-adjusted skewness parameter.

Comment: I probably missed the part on the Wikipedia link you provide, but can you remind me of what $\sigma^{\bf 3}$ represents, and how to get the expression $k_3 = \gamma \sigma^3$?

Comment: @AntoniParellada: Here $\sigma^2$ is the variance, so $\sigma^3 = (\sigma^2)^{3/2}$ is the variance to the power $3/2$.  The expression you give uses notation that is not in the post, but it appears to be giving the relationship between the skewness and the third central moment (see e.g., [definition of skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Definition)).

Comment: In terms of the notation, $k_3=\gamma \sigma^3$ comes from my assumption that $\gamma \sigma^3$ has to be the expression of the third cumulant.

Comment: Well, the skewness is *defined* as $\gamma \equiv \mathbb{E}((\tfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma})^3)$, so you then have $\gamma \sigma^3 = \mathbb{E}((X-\mu)^3) \equiv k_3$.

Comment: Independence occurs when we have a degenerate distribution (an interesting case of your covariance equation since we can have $\text{cov}(X,X^2)=0$ even when $\mu\neq0$ because now $\sigma =0$), or when we have a  scaled Rademacher distribution with $p=0.5$.