# Expected value and standard deviation of $X^2$ in terms of moments of $X$

Tags: probability, expected-value, discrete-data

If $X$ is a discrete random variable with expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, and $Y = X^2$, how can we describe the expected value and standard deviation of $Y$?

Would expected value of $Y = \mu^2$?

Answer (score 2):

For the mean, the answer is simple:
$$E[Y]=E[X^2]=\operatorname{var}(X)+E[X]^2=\sigma^2+\mu^2$$

But, you can't find the variance of $Y$, without the fourth moment of $X$ because:
$$\operatorname{var}(Y)=E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2=E[X^4]-(\sigma^2+\mu^2)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The variance is given in [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452540/).  The mean of $X^2$ depends on the first two moments of $X$ and the variance of $X^2$ depends on the first four moments of $X$.  These are:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X^2) 
&= \mu^2 + \sigma^2, \\[6pt]
\mathbb{V}(X^2) 
&= 4 \mu^2 \sigma^2 + 4 \mu \gamma \sigma^3 + (\kappa-1) \sigma^4, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where $\gamma$ and $\kappa$ are the skewness and kurtosis of $X$.  (To get the standard deviation you just take the square-root of the variance.)